# Grant a permission that wasn't requested by an application

Tags: android, adb, android-manifest, android-permissions

I deliberately keep an old version of ES file explorer 1.6.2.2. It is the last of the good versions of this app.

Everything is fine, but I cannot install APKs in Android 9 by simply tapping on them in ES file explorer as I did in Android 4.3. Have to do this in other application.

My idea was to grant corresponding permission using ADB:

```
adb shell pm grant com.estrongs.android.pop android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES
```

but it results in error:

> Package com.estrongs.android.pop has not requested permission android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES

Of course. This permission isn't in its manifest. At the time this application was developed, such permission did not yet exist. It was't needed.

Is there some way to force granting the permission that isn't in application's manifest?